# Disable auto resize of Bootstrap carousel images

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-carousel

How can I disable resizing of the `carousel` when browser is resized or at least establish a minimum width?

For example [here](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Full-Width-Responsive-Carousel-with-jQuery-Bootstrap/) If I resize the window to `200x600 px` the carousel images are barely visible and they generate an empty space underneath the carousel.

What I would like to have instead is something similar to [hostel world website](http://www.hostelworld.com) where even if I resize the window, the carousel images are not "squeezed".

I tried to give `.carousel` and `.item` `min-width, width` etc but it doesn't respect anything.

```
.item {
     //height: 100%;
    //width: 100%;
    //height: 640px;
    //width: 640px;
    //height: 100vh;
    min-width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;

}

.carousel {
    //min-height: 640px;
    min-width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    //width: 100%;
    //height: 100%;
    //height: 640px;
    //width: 640px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this:

```
/* Carousel img stop resizing
 * image proportion 1920 x 1280
 */
@media screen and (max-width: 450px){
  .carousel-inner>.item>a>img,
  .carousel-inner>.item>img {
    max-width: 450px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden; 
  }
}
```

you may of course establish any breakpoint and proportion ... it stops resizing at 450 px and keeps the image fix at the right side of the screen ...

to keep the image centered when it stops resizing add the following css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 450px){
  .carousel-inner>.item>a>img,
  .carousel-inner>.item>img {
    ...
    margin-left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
}
```